# Hypothesis testing for difference in proportions when given only the 25th percentile (Q1), Median, and 75th percentile (Q3)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

I have a question for an exam:

A researcher hypothesizes that the proportion of students who spend more than $200 on books is greater for students in the social sciences than that for the students in humanities.
The researcher draws independent random samples of 60 students from each of the areas:
[image: Statistics]

Carry out a test at the 0.05 level of significance to see if there is evidence to support the researcher's hypothesis. The Null Hypothesis is that there is no difference between humanities and social sciences in the proportion of the Universities students in the past semester who spend more than $200 on books.

This the only given information for the problem. Since I don't know the raw data, how would I know the proportion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Q3 = 200 for Humanities and median = 200 for Social science,you can create a table: (suppose no student spend exact 200)

```
                  Humanities  Social science
                ------------------------------
     above 200       15             30
     below 200       45             30 
       ----------------------------------------
```

Then you can perform Pearson Chi-Square test or Fisher's exact test.